# Как сделать полный круг градиентом html+css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Пробовал разные варианты из интернета, но они только работали с полукругом, т.е. квадратом с круглыми краями, помогите сделать градиент со 100% кругом

```
.fe-1{text-align: center; border: 5px solid #62bdfc; width: 150px; height:150px;line-height: 100px; border-radius: 100%; margin: 20px 10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top
```

Comment: хоть картинкой дайте то что хотите получить?

Answer (score 1):

Не очень ясно, что нужно получить в итоге. Круг с градиентом? Можно попробовать вот так:
`<div class="rotating">THE END</div>`

```
.rotating {
  background-image: linear-gradient(pink, white);/*Можно radial-gradient*/
  border: 2px solid pink;
  border-radius: 60px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

пожалуйста, напишите конкретнее, что вы хотите в итоге получить.
если вы имеете в виду радиальный градиент, то это можно легко сделать:

```
background: radial-gradient(3em, skyblue 50%, steelblue 70%);
```